# Making ionic to open apps in landscape mode

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I wrote an app by using ionic framework. But it opens in portrait mode. I want it to open in `landscape` mode. In phonegap, we have a global config.xml file where we can use
`<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />`. Is there any similar method for ionic?

Comment: Are you develop the app for android

Comment: yeah, I'm developing the app for android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your android manifest file change this `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to 
`android:screenOrientation="landscape"`.This will work fine for me

Comment: so my answer is helpful for you?

Comment: You shouldn't change anything in the android folder, because that gets (re-)generated by ionic and your changes will dissapear. Change it in the config.xml instead like @alexniver says in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

add

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

in config.xml  works for me

Comment: Small detail: the question was for landscape. So write landscape instead of portrait. But I can confirm this works.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't force that with ionic. You have to use your config.xml file.