# Ionic serve Landscape mode

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I've start developing a app with Ionic (ionic start name blank), and in development I'm using the ionic serve --lab.

Everything is working fine, I already have done others app with Ionic before, but the problem is, this app need to work in landscape mode, and it need to remain in that orientation. And I can't do that.

I already changed the config.xml and added a new preference:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape"/>
```

And also I tried to use this Cordova plugin:
http://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

With no luck again. Everytime I start the serve function the app is served in portrait mode. There's a way I can develop my app (and serve it) in landscape mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making ionic to open apps in landscape mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977361/making-ionic-to-open-apps-in-landscape-mode)

Answer (score 1):

Using Chrome, you can type

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>

and after that

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

You can choose any type of screen/mode.